# How do I call delegate methods for a UITextField within a XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uitextviewdelegate

I have a XIB `ProfileView` contained within a custom `UIViewController` class `Alarm`. `ProfileView` has a subview `UITextView`, and I want to call `UITextView` delegate methods from my custom class `Alarm` instead of `ProfileView` because all of my logic concerning the text of the `UITextView` is in my `Alarm` class. So my question is: Can I call `UITextView` delegate methods from my `Alarm` class if the `UITextView` is a subview of `ProfileView`? In other words, can I set the `UITextView` delegate to `Alarm` instead of `self`?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want *two* delegates for the UITextField? And what do you mean by "access delegate methods?" Delegate methods are called by the requesting object, not something you would "access" yourself. An object should have one-and-only-one delegate, so if you're wanting multiple objects to be informed of some change in the UITextField, then perhaps registering for notifications is more appropriate? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so perhaps you can add more context to your question.

Comment: @christopherdrum thanks for adding clarity. I've edited my question. Hopefully it makes sense what I'm asking. I just want to call my `UITextView` delegate methods from `Alarm` instead of `ProfileView`.

Comment: @AustinBerenyi Sorry but can I know why my answer can't be accepted as right answer? Your question has objective-c tag and you mark a Swift answer as right answer. One more, my answer is earlier answer. Be fair!

Comment: @trungduc sorry for the mistake. Your answer should have been marked as the right answer first. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Connect and make `UITextView` as a public property of `ProfileView`

  ```
  @interface ProfileView : UIView
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
  @end
  ```
- In your `Alarm` class, set `self.profileView.textView.delegate = self` and implement functions you need or if `profileView` isn't a property of `Alarm`, set delegate after you initialize it.

  ```
  @interface Alert : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

  @property (nonatomic, strong) ProfileView* profileView;

  @end

  // In |viewDidLoad| or anywhere after you initialize |_profileView|
  self.profileView.textView.delegate = self;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

By code in `Alarm`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // If you have the UITextField @IBOutlet in your Alarm
    textField.delegate = self

    // If it's owned by ProfileView
    profileView.textField.delegate = self
}
```

Be sure `Alarm` is conformed to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

---

Or with Interface Builder, first drag from the `UITextField` to the `Alarm` object like this:

[image]

And then select **delegate**.

[image]